# Possible value of Variable when given two threads are running parallely?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

The problem is from question paper at [Stanford.](https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter13/downloads/Midterm%20(Winter%202012).pdf) The description of it is as follows:

Suppose two threads execute the following C code concurrently, accessing shared variables a, b,
and c:

**Initialization**

```
int a = 4;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
```

**Thread 1:**

```
if (a < 0) { 
 c = b - a;
} else {
 c = b + a;
}
```

**Thread 2:**

```
b = 10;
a = -3
```

What are the possible values for `c` after both threads complete? You can assume that reads and
writes of the variables are atomic, and that the order of statements within each thread is preserved in the code generated by the C compiler.

**Answer : 4,7,14,13,-3**

I understood the first four outputs as follows, but I'm not able to understand how the output -3 can occur given that order of statements within the thread is preserved.

**4**: Execute thread 1 completely, then execute thread 2.
**7**: Interrupt thread 1 before `c = b + a`, and then execute thread 2, followed by executing thread 1 again. 
**14**: Execute thread 2 till `b = 10` is done, then interrupt it, and execute thread 1 completely. 
**13**: Execute thread 2 completely, then thread 1.

Now I'm stuck on how to obtain -3 as a final value of `c`? -3 is only possible when `b=0`, and `a=-3`, and thread 1 starts its execution from `c = b + a`. I don't see -3 to be possible in any other case. But as mentioned in question, order of statements is maintained, so the value of a can not be -3, unless we change the value of b to 10.

Can someone explain how the output -3 is possible in this case?

Comment: I am surprised to see such a question in an exam of such a respected institution. This is more of a brain-teaser than a programming question.

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly access to non-atomic objects from multiple threads. **Any and all results are permissible, including "elephant"**.

Comment: @EOF That's why I call it a brainteaser, it is not practical - it is listing the assumptions to be made which are not necessarily realistic.

Comment: @EOF is that true if it is assumed that reads and writes are atomic?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd classify this as reckless, especially when used for teaching. Why even pretend that this is C, rather than use some pseudocode where the rules can be made arbitrarily without confusing anybody?

Comment: @GoodDeeds In C, reads and writes of `int`-type are **not atomic**. Full stop. Using this as teaching material is a terrible idea.

Comment: @EOF Maybe because the prerequisites for this course are C only :) ? You know these students... You give them pseudocode and they like: "Hey! we never learnt that notation!"

Comment: Re, " is that true if it is assumed that reads and writes are atomic?" Not quite sure what you are asking, but without any synchronization or _memory barrier_ instructions, then the compiler is free to re-write your code in any way that would yield the same result _in a single-threaded program_, and the hardware is free to execute the instructions out-of-order within the same constraint. Real compilers and real hardware actually _do_ re-order unsynchronized code in order to make it run more efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get `-3` as follows:

1. In thread 1, check `a < 0`, which is false. This takes you to the else condition. Read the value of `b`, which is `0`.
2. Switch to thread 2, execute it completely. `a` is now `-3`.
3. Switch back to thread 1, read `a`, which is `-3`. Then, add and assign `-3` to `c`.

Comment: I had this question in mind looking at your answer :  shouldn't reading b at `c = b + a` execute that instruction atomically, given that reads and writes are done atomically? But yes, now I realize that atomic read and writes does not guarantee that instructions also execute atomically. Am I correct or I misunderstood something? And thanks for your answer, it perfectly makes sense to me now :)

Comment: Based on the assumptions provided by the question, c = b + a would be equivalent to 1. read b, 2. read a, 3. add, 4. write to c. Each read and write being atomic does not necessarily mean that the entire addition operation is atomic.

Comment: @MikePatel, Re, "shouldn't...execute that instruction atomically?" Be careful with your nomenclature there. `c=a+b;` is not an "instruction," It is a C language _statement_. Most C language statements will be compiled into a sequence of machine _instructions_ (e.g., fetch value of b into register 0, fetch value of a into register 1, add value of register 1 to register 0, store value of register 0 into c.)